# Opt out Sitecore Analytics

Tags: xdb

I am new to Sitecore 8.2 and we decided to comply to GDPR. And we are planning to give the site visitor the right to decide if he is going to allow us to collect suc info. If removing `Sitecore.VisitorIdentification()` on pages be the right thing to opting out?

Comment: No I don't think that would be. I believe you would want to refer to the official documentation for 8.2.7.

Comment: The name Sitecore.VisitorIdentification() might be a bit misleading. It is only used for robots detection. What you're looking for is disabling xdb tracking until a user has given consent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to be on 8.2 update 7. But the proper way to do this is to execute the right to be forgotten code on the contact. This will clear all the PII facets in history and going forward. If you just delete the `Sitecore.VisitorIdentification()`, you still have info you have gathered in the past.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/technical-guidance-for-gdpr--including-exm-and-sitecore-commerce-.html

When you run this code against a contact, it will remove all the PII information from the Sitecore facets. If you have your own facets that you created, you will need to handle those also.

```
var args = new Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.RemoveContactPiiSensitiveData.RemoveContactPiiSensitiveDataArgs(contactId);
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run("removeContactPiiSensitiveData", args);
```

Some good info on this SE thread also 
[Sitecore, personal data and General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12/sitecore-personal-data-and-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent collecting data in the first place, I would set a custom cookie to hold such indicator. And build a custom pipeline as described in [Disable xDB tracking for single requests](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/disable-xdb-tracking-for-single-requests) to stop / prevent tracking based on this cookie value.
The visitor identification is also used to indicate and detect whether someone is a robot or not, and not detecting this properly can have unwanted side effects such as swift/unexpected session expiry.

For all other GDPR requirements, the previous reply points you in the right direction for 8.2